# asp.net which data control best for displaying dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have some 20 pages to be developed, mostly containing data shown in tabular format. Columns and data are all different for all pages.

I was wondering that I could create a user control which can create the columns dynamically, but I am stuck with which data control of asp.net would be best in terms of performance and easy to implement. That way I can just have a single user control used in all pages.

Please help me out with your valuable suggestions. If there is some other better way to handle this situation, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

For display of tabular data with [auto column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) naming a [GridView](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) is probably the way to go. It's incredibly easy to implement, just bind your data to the view and you are done.

If performance is the primary concern, I think (but am not certain) that a repeater is faster. 
I doubt it makes /that much/ difference tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Youd do not need to implement a custom user control: [GriView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) does this out of the box - check out the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property.